# How get each character from a word with special encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, tokenize

I need to get an array with all the characters from a word, but the word has letters with special encoding like á, when I execute the follow code:

```
$word = 'withá';

$word_arr = array();
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++) {
    $word_arr[] = $word[$i];
}
```

or

```
$word_arr = str_split($word);
```

I get:

> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "w" [1]=> string(1) "i" [2]=> string(1) "t"
>   [3]=> string(1) "h" [4]=> string(1) "Ã" [5]=> string(1) "¡" }

How can I do to obtain each character as follow?

> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "w" [1]=> string(1) "i" [2]=> string(1) "t"
>   [3]=> string(1) "h" [4]=> string(1) "á" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a UTF-8 string,  just do

```
$word = 'withá';
$word = utf8_decode($word);
$word_arr = array();
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++) {
    $word_arr[] = $word[$i];
}
```

The reason for this is that, even though it looks right in your script, the interpreter converts it into a multibyte character (why `mb_split()` works as well).  To convert it to proper UTF-8 format, you can use the mb functions or just specify `utf8_decode()`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I think mb_split will do it for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php</strike>

If you're using special encodings, you probably want to read up on how PHP handles multibyte encoding in general...

EDIT: Nope, can't figure out how to make mb_split do it myself, but looking around SO got some other questions that were answered with preg_split.  I tested this and it seems to do exactly what you want:

```
preg_split('//',$word,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I'd still strongly suggest you read up on multibyte characters in PHP though.  It's kind of a mess, IMHO.

Here's some good links:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
and
http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/
and plenty more can be found...

Comment: Which is the $pattern (first parameter of mb_split function) you recommends to use for this case?

Comment: `mb_split` is not exactly what is needed.  It only splits based on a regex.  It does not directly split the string into an array of characters.  About half-way through the comments on the page for the function, however, is a function that will do what is needed.

Comment: @G-Nugget - excellent point, even if it's somewhat counter-intuitive.  I couldn't make it work either, and have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the multibyte-Functions for all Multibyte Charsets! I guess mb_split is the pendant:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php

Answer (score 0):

as found on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658

```
    function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
        if ($l > 0) {
            $ret = array();
            $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
            for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
                $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
            }
            return $ret;
        }
        return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }

   $word = 'withá';
   $word = str_split_unicode($word);
   var_dump($word);
```

Comment: Doesn't works, this returns: array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "w" [1]=> string(1) "i" [2]=> string(1) "t" [3]=> string(1) "h" [4]=> string(2) "Ã¡" }

Comment: that is strange, on my server i get: array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "w" [1]=> string(1) "i" [2]=> string(1) "t" [3]=> string(1) "h" [4]=> string(2) "á" }

Comment: @leticia2602 - I'm guessing your file isn't saved with utf-8 encoding - if Tim Withers answer worked for you and this one doesn't, your file is probably encoded with some other encoding.  Try using an editor (like Notepad2) that lets you specify the encoding.

Comment: @Slave I have PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Comment: @Aerik I'm getting the value from a MySql table with Collation: utf8_general_ci

Comment: @leticia2602 Ok - I think you still need to execute `SET NAMES UTF8;` in MySQL, and I think you should encode your PHP source code file in UTF-8 as well.